# How to merge various levels into one attribute after dummy coding the data in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, categorical-data, dummy-variable, levels

I have dummy coded the data in R using the package named "dummies". This gave me the output in various levels and create the dummies for each level. I want to consolidate all those levels on the basis of attributes. Please help me out! Thanks in advance. The following is the code I used:

```
#To read the data from the working directory
bankfull<-read.csv("bank.csv")
#Calling the library named dummies 
library(dummies)
#Redefining the bankfull data with the dummy codes
bankfull<-dummy.data.frame(bankfull,sep=",")
#Viewing the data after dummy coding
print(bankfull)
```

The output is as follows:

```
#To read the data from the working directory
> bankfull<-read.csv("bank.csv")
> #Calling the library named dummies 
> library(dummies)
dummies-1.5.6 provided by Decision Patterns

> #Redefining the bankfull data with the dummy codes
> bankfull<-dummy.data.frame(bankfull,sep=",")
> #Viewing the data after dummy coding
> View(bankfull)
> library(carData)
> #Viewing the data after dummy coding
> print(bankfull)
     CHK_ACCT DURATION HISTORY NEW_CAR USED_CAR FURNITURE RADIO_TV EDUCATION RETRAINING AMOUNT SAV_ACCT EMPLOYMENT INSTALL_RATE MALE_DIV
1           0        6       4       0        0         0        1         0          0   1169        4          4            4        0
2           1       48       2       0        0         0        1         0          0   5951        0          2            2        0
3           3       12       4       0        0         0        0         1          0   2096        0          3            2        0
4           0       42       2       0        0         1        0         0          0   7882        0          3            2        0
5           0       24       3       1        0         0        0         0          0   4870        0          2            3        0
6           3       36       2       0        0         0        0         1          0   9055        4          2            2        0
7           3       24       2       0        0         1        0         0          0   2835        2          4            3        0
8           1       36       2       0        1         0        0         0          0   6948        0          2            2        0
9           3       12       2       0        0         0        1         0          0   3059        3          3            2        1
10          1       30       4       1        0         0        0         0          0   5234        0          0            4        0
11          1       12       2       1        0         0        0         0          0   1295        0          1            3        0
12          0       48       2       0        0         0        0         0          1   4308        0          1            3        0
13          1       12       2       0        0         0        1         0          0   1567        0          2            1        0
14          0       24       4       1        0         0        0         0          0   1199        0          4            4        0
15          0       15       2       1        0         0        0         0          0   1403        0          2            2        0
16          0       24       2       0        0         0        1         0          0   1282        1          2            4        0
17          3       24       4       0        0         0        1         0          0   2424        4          4            4        0
18          0       30       0       0        0         0        0         0          1   8072        4          1            2        0
19          1       24       2       0        1         0        0         0          0  12579        0          4            4        0
20          3       24       2       0        0         0        1         0          0   3430        2          4            3        0
21          3        9       4       1        0         0        0         0          0   2134        0          2            4        0
22          0        6       2       0        0         0        1         0          0   2647        2          2            2        0
23          0       10       4       1        0         0        0         0          0   2241        0          1            1        0
24          1       12       4       0        1         0        0         0          0   1804        1          1            3        0
25          3       10       4       0        0         1        0         0          0   2069        4          2            2        0
26          0        6       2       0        0         1        0         0          0   1374        0          2            1        0
27          3        6       0       0        0         0        1         0          0    426        0          4            4        0
28          2       12       1       0        0         0        1         0          0    409        3          2            3        0
29          1        7       2       0        0         0        1         0          0   2415        0          2            3        0
30          0       60       3       0        0         0        0         0          1   6836        0          4            3        0
31          1       18       2       0        0         0        0         0          1   1913        3          1            3        0
32          0       24       2       0        0         1        0         0          0   4020        0          2            2        0
     MALE_SINGLE MALE_MAR_or_WID CO_APPLICANT GUARANTOR PRESENT_RESIDENT REAL_ESTATE PROP_UNKN_NONE AGE OTHER_INSTALL RENT OWN_RES NUM_CREDITS
1              1               0            0         0                4           1              0  67             0    0       1           2
2              0               0            0         0                2           1              0  22             0    0       1           1
3              1               0            0         0                3           1              0  49             0    0       1           1
4              1               0            0         1                4           0              0  45             0    0       0           1
5              1               0            0         0                4           0              1  53             0    0       0           2
6              1               0            0         0                4           0              1  35             0    0       0           1
7              1               0            0         0                4           0              0  53             0    0       1           1
8              1               0            0         0                2           0              0  35             0    1       0           1
9              0               0            0         0                4           1              0  61             0    0       1           1
10             0               1            0         0                2           0              0  28             0    0       1           2
11             0               0            0         0                1           0              0  25             0    1       0           1
12             0               0            0         0                4           0              0  24             0    1       0           1
13             0               0            0         0                1           0              0  22             0    0       1           1
14             1               0            0         0                4           0              0  60             0    0       1           2
15             0               0            0         0                4           0              0  28             0    1       0           1
16             0               0            0         0                2           0              0  32             0    0       1           1
17             1               0            0         0                4           0              0  53             0    0       1           2
18             1               0            0         0                3           0              0  25             1    0       1           3
19             0               0            0         0                2           0              1  44             0    0       0           1
20             1               0            0         0                2           0              0  31             0    0       1           1
21             1               0            0         0                4           0              0  48             0    0       1           3
22             1               0            0         0                3           1              0  44             0    1       0           1
23             1               0            0         0                3           1              0  48             0    1       0           2
24             1               0            0         0                4           0              0  44             0    0       1           1
25             0               1            0         0                1           0              0  26             0    0       1           2
26             1               0            0         0                2           1              0  36             1    0       1           1
27             0               1            0         0                4           0              0  39             0    0       1           1
28             0               0            0         0                3           1              0  42             0    1       0           2
29             1               0            0         1                2           1              0  34             0    0       1           1
30             1               0            0         0                4           0              1  63             0    0       1           2
31             0               1            0         0                3           1              0  36             1    0       1           1
32             1               0            0         0                2           0              0  27             1    0       1           1
     JOB NUM_DEPENDENTS TELEPHONE FOREIGN RESPONSE
1      2              1         1       0        1
2      2              1         0       0        0
3      1              2         0       0        1
4      2              2         0       0        1
5      2              2         0       0        0
6      1              2         1       0        1
7      2              1         0       0        1
8      3              1         1       0        1
9      1              1         0       0        1
10     3              1         0       0        0
11     2              1         0       0        0
12     2              1         0       0        0
13     2              1         1       0        1
14     1              1         0       0        0
15     2              1         0       0        1
16     1              1         0       0        0
17     2              1         0       0        1
18     2              1         0       0        1
19     3              1         1       0        0
20     2              2         1       0        1
21     2              1         1       0        1
22     2              2         0       0        1
23     1              2         0       1        1
24     2              1         0       0        1
25     2              1         0       1        1
26     1              1         1       0        1
27     1              1         0       0        1
28     2              1         0       0        1
29     2              1         0       0        1
30     2              1         1       0        0
31     2              1         1       0        1
32     2              1         0       0        1
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 968 rows ]
```

In the output the dummies are given according to the levels. I need the output according to the attributes. Can I merge all of them without using any third party packages?

Comment: I may be missing something, but isn't that the very purpose of `dummies`, to covert categories to numerics ?  What is the final output you want after merging , can you give an example dataframe as to how it should look like?

Comment: Actually, I am not that much popular with R. So, I am expecting an ouptut with levels like 1,2,3,4 etc. Suppose, there are three levels in Gender - Male, Female and Prefer Not to Say. It would be better if the output gives levels as 1,2,3 under a single head named Gender.

Comment: Given that you have used `sep=","` it seems none of the variables was converted to dummy. Otherwise there would have been  columns like `colname,category` . Besides , if you just want one column , you can just convert the column to factor with  `mydf$mycol<- as.factor(mydf$mycol)` . Dummies is not needed for just that, and will split such a column into three.